# To read the hyperlink path of a text from Excel file via JAVA?

Tags: java, path, hyperlink

I have done up to reading text (String) from Excel file I could leverage the same into my JAVA. But now I have an other query.

Supposing if the text in Excel is a hyperlink I need the link path of that text.

Say: "hyperlink text" path manually mapped to say ("C:\Folder\iamge.jpg")
I want this path in java.

Can any one help me with this!

Answer (score 0):

those are the first 1000 answers to your question. almost all of them are good for you.
http://www.google.com/search?num=1000&hl=en&safe=off&qscrl=1&q=java+excel&aq=f&aqi=g-p1g1g-c1g2g-c1g2g-c1g1&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=